# Fullcalendar dayclick sends multiple requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am facing a problem  with fullcalendar dayClick function.

```
dayClick: function(date) {

                $('#start_date').val(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD H:mm'));
                $('#new-appointment-modal').modal();

                $('#new-appointment-form').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/api/appointments',
                        data: $('#new-appointment-form').serializeJSON(),
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                          toastr[index](value);
                        });
                      $('#new-appointment-modal').modal('hide');
                    }).fail(function(response) {
                      $.each(response.responseJSON, function(index, value) {
                        toastr[index](value);
                      });
                    });
                });
            }
```

This is my function right now.

The problem is that first time I click on a day cell and send the ajax request everything works great, but if I am not refreshing the page and I click on another day cell `dayClick` will send two ajax request, if after that I click on another day, it will send three ajax requests and so on.

I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: When you call `$('#new-appointment-form').submit(...)`, you are registering a submit-event handler on the form. You are doing this each time a day is clicked, so after two clicks, you have registered two event handlers, and so on. You should move that code out so it is executed only once when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnS
I've added the following code in .done and .fail functions
    `$('#new-appointment-form').off("submit");`

and now everything works as expected.